# Can‘t display nested Array Data in ui grid?

Tags: angularjs, multidimensional-array, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I want to display nested data in ui grid, e.g data:

```
[
 [
 { id:1, name:“test1 },
 { id:2, name:“test2 },
 { id:3, name:“test3 },
 { id:4, name:“test4 }
 ],
 [
 { id:5, name:“test1 },
 { id:6, name:“test2 },
 { id:7, name:“test3 },
 { id:8, name:“test4 }
 ]
]
```

idea was to fix it with rowTemplate, but i cant get the data in rowTemplate.html to use ng-repeat for the nested data, i will display multiple data in same row, i don’t want use ui grid grouping.
I think ui grid not process data if data is nested array as up, same if i will config it with celltemplate row.entity is empty and blank.
e.g. rowTemplate.html

```
<div
 ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
 ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'"
 class="ui-grid-cell"
 ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }"
 role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}"
 ui-grid-cell>

 <!—  Here i would like to use ng-repeat for the nested data but
  row.entity , colRenderIndex, col each is empty if i use {{ 
  row.entity col, ... }} result is empty blank —>

</div>
```

Pls help.

Comment: Why you have to use nested data? ui-grid is used for displaying data, you can extract the data for to one layer array for ui-grid.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple. All your data resides in the first object of your array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <!--<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid"
             ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + '-' + col.uid + '-cell'"
             class="ui-grid-cell"
             ng-class="{ 'ui-grid-row-header-cell': col.isRowHeader }"
             role="{{col.isRowHeader ? 'rowheader' : 'gridcell'}}"
             ui-grid-cell>-->

            <!—  Here i would like to use ng-repeat for the nested data but
            row.entity , colRenderIndex, col each is empty if i use {{
  row.entity col, ...
            }} result is empty blank —>
        {{data}}
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="row in data[0]">
                    <td>{{row.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <!--</div>-->
    </div>

    <script src="../lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('app', []);
        app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.data=[
                 [
                 { id:1, name:'test1' },
                 { id:2, name:'test2' },
                 { id:3, name:'test3' },
                 { id:4, name:'test4' }
                 ],
                 [
                 { id:5, name:'test1' },
                 { id:6, name:'test2' },
                 { id:7, name:'test3'},
                 { id:8, name:'test4' }
                 ]
            ]
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @huanfeng: instead of down voting without any reason, read the question again.

Comment: ok, my mistake, system does not allow me to revert the changes unless you have edit the answer a little bit.